# Setting a Custom Cubic Bezier Curve in Swiper JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, swiper.js

I'm working with Swiper JS, and I want to set a custom cubic bezier curve for the easing of the slide animation. Specifically, I want to create and use my own cubic bezier easing function. How can I achieve this in Swiper JS?

Here's one of the things that i tried:

```
const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
    effect: "slide",
    loop: true,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
    },
    speed: 1000,
    easing: "cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1)" // This is not working, ease: doesn't work too
});
```

However, the code above doesn't seem to be working as expected. How can I set a custom cubic bezier easing function in Swiper JS? Is there a specific format or method I should use for custom cubic bezier curves in Swiper JS?

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a property called "ease" where you set a custom ease value. But you can add a `transition-timing-function` CSS property to the `.swiper-wrapper` element in your CSS to change the easing to a custom bezier curve. There's also a custom property, `--swiper-wrapper-transition-timing-function` which you can update to change the easing.